# Read again specific kafka messages after having read à lot

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-cloud-stream, spring-kafka

I have build a SpringBoot service which uses SpringCloud @StreamListener in order to process kafka messages.

Let's assume I have a kafka topic on which a lot of messages have already been published. My @StreamListener consumer is able to read those messages with the stream.

Let's imagine, the current offset is, for example, 300 and I notice some error with message 200. I would like to reprocess it.

Is it possible to read again the message with offset 200 and to skip already read messages with greater offset ? Or will I have to replay also all messages from 201 to 300 ?

Comment: Yes, conceptually you can access any offset arbitrarily from your code. Are you asking about a specific language/library?

Comment: Thank you. Yes I am used to work with kafka with spring cloud stream

Comment: I'd suggest updating the tags & description in your question to include this information, hopefully someone with experience of this framework can help you out with specifics

Comment: You are right Robin. I have amended with that information.

Comment: I am not familiar with Spring Cloud Stream. Using `KafkaConsumer` you can use `seek()` to go to a specific offset. Hope this helps.